# How can I present an array of booleans in a panel?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties

I'm trying to provide a tool for an artist on my gameDev project.  They should be able to set a bunch of settings in a panel, and then press a button to start an automated export.  I want to give let them set a bunch of boolean values, but I'm having trouble finding a good way to present a lot of booleans in the Blender UI.

[image: UI Mockup:]

I need to iterate over the values in each list, so having a BoolProperty for every checkbox is not an option.

I am not sure what kind of layout.prop would do this well, or what kind of property data structure to use with it.

On the UI side, prop_menu_enum() seems like it would be perfect...can I use it as to hold multiple UI checkboxes?  Otherwise I could iterate over whatever kind of list of booleans I end up with and a property for each one.

On the data structure side, I see there is a BoolVectorProperty, but it doesn't seem to hold names for each value.  There's a CollectionProperty, but I'm getting a error "TypeError: CollectionProperty(...): expected an RNA type derived from PropertyGroup, failed with type 'builin_function_or_method'" when I try to register a PropertyGroup that has a CollectionProperty as a member variable.

I keep getting the feeling that there's some good way to do this that I don't know about (and I know almost nothing about blender programming).  Any recommendations?

Comment: You can use `prop_menu_item` to hold multiple UI checkboxes if you pass the `ENUM_FLAG` option to the corresponding [EnumProperty](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty). Don't specify the numids then. Blender uses powers of 2 for single elements and sums for combinations in this case. (bit field)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works pretty well to use BoolVectorProperty and then in the UI to address each element by specifying the index and overriding the (empty) text.  I learned this reading http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-264624.html .

ex:

```
myList = ["cat", "rabbit", "fox"]

class SpriteSheetProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    sets = bpy.props.BoolVectorProperty(
        name = "Sets",
        description = "Which animal sets to render",
        size = len(SETS),)

class SpritifyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        box = layout.box()
        split = box.split(.25)
        column = split.column()
        for i,set in enumerate(SETS):
            column.row().prop(context.scene.spritesheet, 'sets', index=i, text=set)
```

Doing this over a few different list, I now have this nice box:

[image: UI implemented]

Comment: You can use [`column_flow`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.column_flow) if you don't want to split things manually. Other layout options are listed on the linked page.